# Select multiple records using where statement

Tags: sql, where-clause

I am using the following:

```
select * from far
where itemno = '100701'
```

This gives me 1 record.

What I want is to get multiple records with variable for itemno:

```
select * from far
where itemno = '100701', '100702', '100703......
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

```
select * from far where itemno in ('100701', '100702', '100703, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple

```
select * from far where itemno IN ('100701', '100702', '100703.....)
```